# using app.config file for connection string, and abstract it from users

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, app-config

I have used app.config file for my winform application , the file is used to store the connection string which is used by all the Forms in my application to connect to a remote MySQL database.

But when I install the application on my customer's PCs, then I want that they could not see the app.config file. Is it possible? How? Please help with code.

Also, is there any other way, to create a connection string which is accessible by all the Forms. Like, can I make a class **connection.cs** and then inherit it in every Form.
But how to do this? I mean how to implement the code

My main objective is to create just one string for connection, so that , if i change it again and again, then i need not go and change it every Form, instead, i would just change it only in one File , and it would be used by all the Forms

Is using app.config file a good option or making a connection.cs file's a better one?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a connection string from every form, you need a data access layer and then you use it from everywhere, in theory only from another layer called business logic...

A form which needs to load data into a grid, a drop down or some other controls should consume data loaded by lower layers in your application stack.

Read something about 3 tier architecture.

Comment: ok sir, so you mean , i should not use--- OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};uid=ab ; password=pass;server=www.myweb.com;database=mydb;port=3306");  ----in the Form.cs files, then where shall i add this code?

Comment: not in every form my god! you create a class which not only handles the connection string but the whole connection logic and consumption, exposing methods like GetTable, GetScalar, ExecuteQuery and so on... or have also a look at Microsoft Entity Framework.

Comment: My application loads and inserts data in the mysql database, so i need a connection string to establish a connection to the database. i have combobox controls, grids which load data from the database. so where shall i add the connection string ?

Comment: ok sir, so i am naming the connection file as CONNECTION.CS, now can you please help me out with the code. my connection string is --OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};uid=ab ; password=pass;server=www.myweb.com;database=mydb;port=3306");

Answer (score 1):

The app.config is always visible on the user machine, so you should not treat any information stored in it as secret.

You really have two options:

- Continue to store the connection string in the app.config but encrypt it. This will work fine if its an internal app and security is not to much of an issue. But since the encryption key has to be stored in the app a dedicated hacker could retrieve it.
- use a three tier architecture as suggested already. With this the connection string is stored in the middle tier, while your application no longer connects directly to the database but rather through the middle tier. Authentication can then be done with a user name/password per user or by making use of windows authentication. The connection string is stored on a server and only people with acces to this server can look at it and see the DB connection string.

Comment: @Robert Anton Reese : sir, what is 'middle tier ' here, i mean , a database, a connection.cs file or else?

Comment: For a simple example say we have a windows form that saves user input into the DB. The simplest way to do this is to put an ADO or EF call to the DB in the code behind file. With multi tier architecture your code behind file wouldn't call the DB directly rather it would call a WCF service sending the data to save. Then the WCF service would save the data to the database. Since the WCF service lives on its own server the app.config is restricted to the users of that one machine.

Comment: Wikipedia has a decent overview of the pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture

Comment: @Robert Anton Reese : ok sir, so shall i use app.config or not? or shall i create connection.cs class and inherit it in all Forms

Comment: I don't think it really matters, as long as you encrypt the connection string (see Bibhu's link). In projects that I have worked on in the past where we didn't use a 3 tier architecture we encrypted the connection string in the app.config file. But once more this isn't as secure as a 3 tier architecture and you shouldn't do this if your DB contains medical, financial or otherwise really sensitive information. Obviously though doing a straight DB connection minimizes a lot of overhead and allows you to write your application faster.

Comment: @Robert Anton Reese: but sir, if i use app.config then it could be edited or deleted by the user,i want to hide it, or include it in resources or assembly. how do i do this

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a simple solutions why not create a class named for example "Connection" in a file connection.cs and let it have a static attribute or property named for example "ConString" which holds the connection string:

```
public class Connection
{
  public static ConString = "your connection string here";
}
```

Then you can access it everywhere:

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(Connection.ConString);
```

BUT that would only be the quick and dirty way of doing it (although it works). It would be much nicer to create an own Database-Layer - but also much more work.

Comment: sir , thanks a lot, also , can you please guide me for going to creating an own Database Layer. am ready to do a lots of work, its just that the choice which i chose must be EFFICIENT and A GOOD  one, then only i would be called a good programmer indeed

Answer (score 0):

App.config can't be hidden on users machine, this is what you can do.
You can encrypt the connection string and store it in the app.config. have a look on this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/EncryptingTheAppConfig.aspx), it shows you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your connection string in program.cs before [statThread] by storing it in a public static string variable like constr etc. Then u can use that var anywhere referencing:
program.constr